# Does codename support java applications that integrate the spring container？

Tags: codenameone

I have a java service application integrated with spring container，which is running on Android and windows. Can I port it to run in iOS platform using codename one?  I read the documentation carefully and it says that reflection is not supported. IOC uses reflection function in spring framework. Does it mean that codename one cannot be used？

The output jar package size of my project is 98m, I have tried to modify the codename plugin source to remove the jar package size limit(50m). But I got an error when I compiled with xcode iOS project:

```
[INFO] Exception in thread "main" 
[INFO] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
[INFO] 
[INFO]  at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:832)
[INFO] 
[INFO]  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readConst(ClassReader.java:3800)
[INFO] 
[INFO]  at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:2398)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1491)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:721)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:401)
    at com.codename1.tools.translator.Parser.parse(Parser.java:69)
    at com.codename1.tools.translator.ByteCodeTranslator.execute(ByteCodeTranslator.java:102)
    at com.codename1.tools.translator.ByteCodeTranslator.execute(ByteCodeTranslator.java:117)
    at com.codename1.tools.translator.ByteCodeTranslator.execute(ByteCodeTranslator.java:117)
    at com.codename1.tools.translator.ByteCodeTranslator.execute(ByteCodeTranslator.java:117)
    at com.codename1.tools.translator.ByteCodeTranslator.execute(ByteCodeTranslator.java:76)
    at com.codename1.tools.translator.ByteCodeTranslator.main(ByteCodeTranslator.java:241)
[INFO] Process return code is 1
```

I have added memory params “-DXmx8192m” for maven，but this error still occurs.

Answer (score 1):

No.

It wouldn't work since we don't support proxies, reflection, bytecode manipulation, etc. So all the IoC tools in Spring won't work.

Supporting them would mean a VM size that's huge and impractical for a mobile device.